# Hibernate: use a single table for two different classes

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm working on an application that should support `Employees` and `Customers`. The `Customers` have an `Address`, the `Employees` do not. I do not wish to create two separate tables in the database for them. In the database I have a `users`, a `roles` and a `users_roles` table that indicates whether a user is an Employee or a Customer.

Here is what I have going on:

```
users
------
id
first_name
last_name
credentials_id (the username from `credentials`)
```

```
credentials
------
username
password
```

```
addresses
------
id
city
country
street
```

```
users_addresses
------
user_id
address_id
```

And here is how the hibernate mappings look like:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "firstName", column = @Column(name = "first_name")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "lastName", column = @Column(name = "last_name"))
    })
    private UserDetails userDetails;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "customers_addresses",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "address_id")})
    private Address address;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "firstName", column = @Column(name = "first_name")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "lastName", column = @Column(name = "last_name"))
    })
    private UserDetails userDetails;
}
```

```java
@Embeddable
public class UserDetails {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "credentials_id")
    private UserCredentials credentials;
}
```

It all works fine but when I query the employees (with `createQuery("from Employee")` they have a `address` field on them that is `null`. Also, when I query the customers (with `createQuery("from Customers")`, the result includes employees as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Employee` doesn't have a field `address`, do you expect it to be set?

Comment: I expect running `createQuery("from Employee")` not to return an object with an `address`.

Comment: createQuery("from Employee").getResultList(); it will return a `List<Employee>`. `address` won't appear anywhere. I'm not sure if this is a doubt you have or something that's actually happening to you.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a `users`, a `roles` and a `users_roles` table that indicates whether a user is an `Employee` or a `Customer`.

Can `Employee`s and `Customer`s switch roles?

If not, the most sensible solution would be to use inheritance:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(SINGLE_TABLE)
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Embedded
    private UserDetails userDetails;

}

@Entity
public class Customer extends User {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "customers_addresses",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "address_id")})
    private Address address;
}

@Entity
public class Employee extends User {}
```

With the above setup, `from Employees` will return employees only, `from Customers` - customers, and `from Users` will select all `User`s. The downside is, of course, redundant information in the form of a discriminator column.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't want to use inheritance, you probably need a `@Filter`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@SecondaryTable(
    name = "user_roles",
    pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_id")
)
@FilterDef(
    name="filterByRole",
    parameters = @ParamDef( name="roleId",type="int" )
)
@Filter(
    name="filterByRole",
    condition="{ur}.role_id = :roleId",
    aliases = @SqlFragmentAlias( alias = "ur", table= "user_roles")
)
class Employee {
}
```

The drawback is that you need to enable it before querying:

```
entityManager
    .unwrap( Session.class )
    .enableFilter( "filterByRole" )
    .setParameter( "roleid", employeeRoleId);

List<Employee> employees = entityManager
    .createQuery("from Employee", Employee.class)
    .getResultList();
```

See [the filters section on the Hibernate ORM documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter-sql-fragment-alias)

[There is also a `@Where` annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filtering), but I don't think it's going to work for your case, unless you can filter using only the columns in the table `users`.

Comment: 'from Employee return an object with the address because you didn't specify the entity class' - well, not really. It returns objects with addresses because JPA has no way of knowing that an object with an address is not supposed to be an Employee. It simply assumes the entire content of the table represents Employees as there's nothing in the mapping that would suggest otherwise.

Comment: Something is not right, when Hibernate ORM convert the query form HQL to SQL, it will add the needed columns in the SQL. Employee doesn't have an address column so it shouldn't appear in the SQL select clause. I don't see why it would add the address column since it's not an Employee field.

Comment: I've removed that comment about passing the entity